# Auto-filling a database.(Android/Newbie)

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

Is there a way to create a database from a text file? I want to include a pre-populated DB with an app, but cannot find the right words to search for what I need. I'm looking to have each separate word in the text file (a list of names) be assigned it's own ID and stored in the database. I want all of this done on my end, so that the DB is already set up and ready to go when the user downloads the app. I know you can store a .db in the assets folder, but it's the actual generation of the .db that has left me stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text file is properly formated (e.g. as CSV), you can import it via the sqlite3 executable. [See here](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles).

```
sqlite> create table myTable (id integer, col_a integer, col_b integer, col_c text);
sqlite> .separator ","
sqlite> .import myFile.csv myTable
```

If you want to do it via GUI, I recommend [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/). It's easy enough to populate the tables by hand, and you can also execute queries directly (*Tools* => *Open Query Editor*). If you want to import from there, first create the table to fill, then highlight it and select *Tables* => *Import data to table*.

Comment: Sorry for the (extremely) late reply. I was looking through my old questions and found this!

Answer (score 1):

Generate a couple of INSERT statements from your data, execute against an sqlite tool of your choice, save the db file, done. Or ship the sql statements for insertion with your app. Both ways work.

So you use some tool (like e.g. [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/), I personally use [Pentaho Data Integration/Kettle](http://kettle.pentaho.com/)) locally to create the db file. Then you put that file in your /assets folder and ship it with the app. On first startup you copy the file from /assets to the db folder (there's plenty of tutorials out there on how to do this).

Or, on startup you create the db from scratch and instead of the db file you pre-create (with any tool you feel comfortable with) a file with sql statements which you then read and execute against your newly created db.

I did it both ways and both ways work, you have to try out what is less trouble/faster in your setup.

Comment: So what you are saying is I should write an app to do it for me? That's kinda what I was trying to avoid. I'm an absolute newbie with databases (not just SQLite) and was trying to mess around with data manipulation before handling data management.